# CKAN - Customize Style in each Organization

Tags: python, ckan, opendata

I am using CKAN as an OpenData portal and I have an instance correctly running with its own Datasets, Groups and Organizations.

I was following the [Theming Guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/templates.html) having got finally my own global site style configured. Despite of that my Organizations are very different between themselves and I would like to go further. How could I customize each Organization with their own style?

I am not sure if the only way is to write an [extension](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/tutorial.html) (o rewrite Organization template) to add a "custom.css" file in the creation of an organization and load it each time is accessed. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've changed the main CSS by setting config option `ckan.main_css`.

However you can't do much more visual customization without creating an extension, so I'd encourage you to do that. It's the first step in the [Theming guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/templates.html).

See also the [CSS section of the Theming guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/css.html).

How you theme it depending on organization depends on the page you're targeting. But no doubt you could add some Jinja logic to load a different CSS file, or insert classes to CSS select on, depending on the organization.